# Brew process leak

Tags: homebrew

Since I upgraded to El Captain, I'm having trouble with `Homebrew`, specifically when exhausting the resources by spawning dozens of process from time to time.

I get this error:

```
fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

And with the output of `ps -ax | grep ruby`, I get:

```
 8394 ??         0:00.15 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
 8503 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
 8611 ??         0:00.17 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
 8719 ??         0:00.14 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
 8827 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
 8935 ??         0:00.14 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
 9043 ??         0:00.14 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
 9152 ??         0:00.14 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
 9260 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
 9368 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
 9476 ??         0:00.14 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
 9584 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
 9698 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
 9807 ??         0:00.15 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
 9915 ??         0:00.15 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
10024 ??         0:00.15 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
10132 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
10242 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
10350 ??         0:00.14 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
10458 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
10566 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
13963 ??         0:00.06 ruby /Users/pedropaulo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/gem env gemdir
34035 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
34142 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
34249 ??         0:00.12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
34356 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
34465 ??         0:00.12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
34572 ??         0:00.12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
34679 ??         0:00.12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
34786 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
34893 ??         0:00.12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
35000 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
35107 ??         0:00.12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
35214 ??         0:00.12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
35321 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
35428 ??         0:00.12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
35535 ??         0:00.12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
35643 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
35750 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
35857 ??         0:00.12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
35964 ??         0:00.12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
36071 ??         0:00.12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
36178 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
36285 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
36392 ??         0:00.12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
36499 ??         0:00.12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
36606 ??         0:00.12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
36713 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
36821 ??         0:00.12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
36928 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
37035 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
37142 ??         0:00.12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
37249 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
37356 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
37463 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
37570 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
37677 ??         0:00.12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
37784 ??         0:00.12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
37891 ??         0:00.12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
37999 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
38106 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
38213 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
38320 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
38427 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
38534 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
38641 ??         0:00.12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
38748 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
38855 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
38962 ??         0:00.14 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
39069 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
39177 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
39284 ??         0:00.14 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
39391 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb --prefix homebrew/php/php55
```

Does anyone know a fix for this problem?

Comment: What was the command you ran to start this?

Comment: I didn't. Not that I know of.

Comment: So you have a process in LaunchAgents or Daemons -